# regex checking for certain pattern of characters and numbers

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I have users inputting a file in the format of

image[1-4 digits][0-1 alphabet]

for eg :  (valid names)

```
image1
image1f
image1B
image2201
image2201a
```

non valid

```
image (no number specified)
imagez (no number specified)
image12a1 (no digit permitted after letter)
image44aa (only one letter allowed after number)
```

how can i check if the right format has been entered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you want php or javascript.  Here is the JS version:

```
/^image(\d{1,4})([A-Za-z])?$/
```

To extract the number:

```
var result = regex.exec(tests[i]),
    isValid = result !== null,
    number = isValid && result[1],
    lastChar = isValid && result[2];
```

Check out the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ug7XD/2/

Comment: +1 This is correct but you actually don't need the grouping parentheses. Works also with php `preg_match`.

Comment: @Steve Greatrex wanted to know if i can extract the numbers and the last char (if it is there) for eg image2201a need 2201 and a

Comment: @Steve Greatrex http://jsfiddle.net/Ug7XD/3/   - check out "image111a" it should show 111 shows only 1 and a

Answer (score 1):

This should help you...

```
/^image[0-9]{1,4}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}$/
```

Here is explained.
`^` means start of a string, `image` well the string, `[0-9]` is used to identify number from 0 to 9, `{1,4}` means that numbers must be 1 or 4 times, then `[a-zA-Z]` checks for characters, and `{0,1}` checks if there is a 1 character after digit or none, and `$` means the end of the string you supply in variable. The `/` is used to escape the regex string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$pattern = "/^image\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]$/";
```

Comment: This is not correct, only 0 or 1 alpha chars are allowed at the end of the string.

Comment: Changed response to reflect php syntax.  Your regex is in $pattern.